# the contact form dont send me it is show 404

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am a beginner in django and I have had a problem for 1 week now, several tutorials that I have watched have not solved anything, so I trust you.

it's just making the different contact forms of my website designed with django work
I therefore attach the source code of my project and the code, when I launch the send button (submit) I receive a 404 error

```
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
DEFAULT_FORM_EMAIL="ouesergegedeon225@gmail.com"
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'ouesergegedeon225@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Gedeon225@@'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = 'True'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = 'False'
```

```
def send_mail(request):
     if request.method=="POST":
         name = request.POST.get['name']
         subject = request.POST.get['subject']
         email = request.POST.get['email_address']
         message = request.POST.get['message']
         
     send_mail(
            name,
            subject,
            email,
            message,
            'ouesergegedeon225@mail.com',
            ['gedeonachat@mail.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
            )

     message.info (request, 'Votre message a été envoyé')
     return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

```
 path('send_mail/', views.send_mail, name="send_mail"),
```

```
 <form action="send_mail" method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                <div id="message" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Nom et prénom" name="fname">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Le sujet" name="subject">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email_address" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" name="message" id="message" placeholder="message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn v8" >Envoyer le message</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Please show the HTML form that you are using to submit the email.

Comment: check now i add it now, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `action` attribute of your form is incorrect. Either leave it empty (if you're posting to the same view), or use the `url` template tag to generate the correct URL:

```
 <form action="{% url 'send_mail' %}" method="POST">
```

Comment: TypeError at /send_mail/
send_mail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fail_silently'
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/send_mail/
Django Version: 4.0.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
send_mail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fail_silently'
Exception Location: C:\Users\OUE\Desktop\pcibenin\App\views.py, line 43, in send_mail

Comment: That's a completely separate issue, which is that your function `send_mail` has the same name as the imported `django.core.mail.send_mail`, and replaces it. You need to change the name of your function so that it doesn't collide.